# Como sumar propiedades de un objeto?

Tags: javascript, funciones, javascript-metodo

tengo 3 resultados con la propiedades equipos y  medallas: Oro, bronze y plata. Necsito totalizar las medallas por pais, es decir sumar los 3 tipos de medallas y asignar el valor a cada pais que corresponde.

No puedo usar ni librerias ni expersions regulares.

si me pueden ayudar se los agradezco-.

```
Estos son mis objetos: 

0: [{team: 'JOR', medal: 'Gold', total: 1}
1: {team: 'GBR', medal: 'Gold', total: 64}
2: {team: 'USA', medal: 'Gold', total: 139}]

0: [{team: 'JOR', medal: 'Silver', total: 55}
1: {team: 'GBR', medal: 'Silver', total: 28}
2: {team: 'USA', medal: 'Silver', total: 25}]

0: {team: 'JOR', medal: 'Bronze', total: 24}
1: {team: 'GBR', medal: 'Bronze', total: 10}
2: {team: 'USA', medal: 'Bronze', total: 4}

Necesito este resultado 

0: {team: 'JOR', totalMedals: 80}
1: {team: 'GBR', totalMedals: 102}
2: {team: 'USA', totalMedals: 168}
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
const computeData = (datos, medal) => { 
  const arrayOfNoc = [];
  const countriesWonMedals = datos.filter(athletes => athletes.medal === medal) 
  for (let i = 0; i < countriesWonMedals.length; i++) { 
    arrayOfNoc.push(countriesWonMedals[i].noc) 
  }
  const teamWithMedals = []; 
  for (let j = 0; j < arrayOfNoc.length; j++) { 
    const totalTeamWithMedals = arrayOfNoc[j] + " "+ medal + " " + arrayOfNoc.filter(team => team === arrayOfNoc[j]).length 
    teamWithMedals.push(totalTeamWithMedals) 
  }
 const eliminatingDuplicateTeams = new Set(teamWithMedals); 
 let newArrayTeamWithMedals = Array.from(eliminatingDuplicateTeams); 
 
   let creatingNewObject = newArrayTeamWithMedals.map(country => ( {      
    team: country.split(" ")[0],    
    medal: country.split(" ")[1],    
    total: Number(country.split(" ")[2])  
  }))
```

Comment: Hola! Qué problema tiene tu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ayudarte de una estructura auxiliar para guardar los resultados totales.

Por otro lado, como quieres saber el total, puedes unificar en un único array todos los resultados de cada tipo de medalla.

Una vez hecho eso podrías utilizar un reduce, pero por simplificarlo, te dejo esta opción:

```js
// datos
const goldMedals = [
  {team: 'JOR', medal: 'Gold', total: 1},
  {team: 'GBR', medal: 'Gold', total: 64},
  {team: 'USA', medal: 'Gold', total: 139}
];

const silverMedals = [
  {team: 'JOR', medal: 'Silver', total: 55},
  {team: 'GBR', medal: 'Silver', total: 28},
  {team: 'USA', medal: 'Silver', total: 25}
];  

const bronzeMedals = [
  {team: 'JOR', medal: 'Bronze', total: 24},
  {team: 'GBR', medal: 'Bronze', total: 10},
  {team: 'USA', medal: 'Bronze', total: 4}
];

// Resultados parciales / temporales
const countryResults = {};

// Calculamos totales
[
  ...goldMedals,
  ...silverMedals,
  ...bronzeMedals
].map(result => {
    const partialResult = countryResults[result.team];
    countryResults[result.team] = partialResult
      ? partialResult + result.total
      : result.total;
});

// Pasamos los resultados al formato array indicado
const totals = Object
  .keys(countryResults)
  .map(totalResult => (
    {
        team: totalResult,
        totalMedals: countryResults[totalResult]
    }
  )
);

// Mostramos por consola
console.log('Resultado: ', totals);
```

Si tienes alguna duda, puedes utilizar los comentarios.

Espero que te pueda servir de ayuda

Comment: gracias, me podrias explicar como funciona el método .keys() por favor!!

Comment: Puedes encontrar una explicación completa del método .keys() [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). De forma resumida, lo que hace es crear un array sólo con las claves del objeto pasado como parámetro

Comment: Si te ha servido la respuesta, por favor, márcala como aceptada para que pueda servir de ayuda y referencia a otros usuarios con una duda similar

Comment: Gracias si me ha servido, donde la puedo marcar?

Comment: [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) tienes información general acerca de las respuestas, y [aquí concretamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), cómo marcarlas como válidas o que te sirvieron a la pregunta planteada

Answer (score 0):

Esta solución es super vainilla Javascript. Simplemente usa una lista con índices el nombre del país, y va sumando las medallas de cada país.
Luego para mantener la estructura de objetos pues convierto esa lista (array) a una lista de objetos {team:'', totalMedals:0}

```
metales =[
[{team: 'JOR', medal: 'Gold', total: 1},
{team: 'GBR', medal: 'Gold', total: 64},
{team: 'USA', medal: 'Gold', total: 139}],

[{team: 'JOR', medal: 'Silver', total: 55},
{team: 'GBR', medal: 'Silver', total: 28},
{team: 'USA', medal: 'Silver', total: 25}],

[{team: 'JOR', medal: 'Bronze', total: 24},
{team: 'GBR', medal: 'Bronze', total: 10},
{team: 'USA', medal: 'Bronze', total: 4}],
];

medallas = [];
metales.forEach((valor)=>contarMedallas(valor, medallas));

total = arrayToObject(medallas);
total.sort((a,b)=>(a.total>b.total?-1:1))
console.log(total);

function arrayToObject(meds)
{
   var  total = [];
   for(key in meds){ 
      total.push({team:key, totalMedals: medallas[key]});
   }
   return total;
}

function contarMedallas(equipo, medallas){
    equipo.forEach( (valor) =>{
        if (medallas[valor.team] == undefined){
            medallas[valor.team] = valor.total;
            }
        else{
            medallas[valor.team] += valor.total;
            }    
        })
}
```